# Error when using "any" operator on inherited entity

Tags: breeze

Breeze version: 1.4.14

I have 2 entities: Person and Patient. Person has a list of Telephones and Patient inherit from Person.

I can query on the server:

```
var patients = Patients.Where(x => x.Telephones.Where(xx => xx.Number == "XXXX-XXXX").Any());
```

I can also get the results pasting this url on the browser:

```
/breeze/Patients?$filter=Telephones/any(x1: x1/Number eq 'XXXX-XXXX')
```

But if I try to execute a breeze query from the client

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Patients");
query = query.where("telephones", "any", "number", "==", "XXXX-XXXX");
```

I get an error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAnonymous' of undefined breeze.debug.js:14807:34"
```

If I change the query to the base table "Person" it works:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Person");
query = query.where("telephones", "any", "number", "==", "XXXX-XXXX");
```

But I really need all the patient data... am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not now if this is a bug but I resolve it by calling `toType()` on my query:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Patients").toType("Patient");
query = query.where("telephones", "any", "number", "==", "XXXX-XXXX");
```

Comment: If you had to call toType() then it is likely that you do not have your resource name/entity type mapping set up. See the "EntityType/ ResourceName map" topic here:   http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/querying-locally

Comment: @JayTraband, if I do not use a "any" condition (but use others) the query works fine!

Comment: I have the same exact issue as @Leo, when using the "any" or "all" I had to use the .toType(), otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Hi use this code to solve your problem...

```
  var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Patients);
  query = query.where("telephones", "breeze.FilterQueryOp.any", "number", "breeze.FilterQueryOp.eq", "XXXX-XXXX");
```